# Buscar un objeto JSON dentro de un array utilizando una propiedad del objeto

Tags: javascript, json, array, api, fetch

Tengo un código que realiza un petición a una API, la cual devuelve un objeto JSON similar al siguiente:

```
[
      {
        "code": "AA1", 
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Ubication 1"
      }, 
      {
        "code": "AA2", 
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Ubication 2"
      }, 
      {
        "code": "AA3", 
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Ubication 3"
      }, 
      {
        "code": "AA4", 
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Ubication 4"
      }
    ]
```

Mi consulta es: Como localizar un objeto especifico dentro del array utilizando el `id` de el objeto desde javascript.

Para obtener el objeto tengo el siguiente código:

```
let villages = fetch(url_villages,{
  method :'GET',
    headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      console.log('OK');
      return res.json();
   }
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.error(err.message);
   })
```

Comment: Utiliza el [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) para encontrar un elemento dentro de un array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `filter`.

```js
const responseData = [
  {
    "code": "AA1", 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Ubication 1"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA2", 
    "id": 2, 
    "name": "Ubication 2"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA3", 
    "id": 3, 
    "name": "Ubication 3"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA4", 
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Ubication 4",
  },
];

const localizarUbicacion = (idUbicacion) => {
  return responseData.filter(
    (ubicacion) => ubicacion.id === idUbicacion,
  )[0] || {};
}

console.log(localizarUbicacion(1));
console.log(localizarUbicacion(3));
console.log(localizarUbicacion(99));
```

Comment: agrega una explicacion al codigo

Comment: Porque usas `filter(...)` y solo devuelves la primera instancia? para eso no seria mejor usar `find(...)` ?

Comment: Al ejecutar el `filter` en la consola devuelve lo siguiente:
`response_villages_data.filter is not a function`

Comment: Sólo puede ser porque `response_villages_data` no es un array. Es la única razón porque `filter` sólo se aplica a arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de si quieres localizar solo la primera instancia o todas puedes usar `filter(...)` o `find(...)`

El ejemplo abajo usa cualquier propiedad en su busqueda.  Espero te sirva de ejemplo.

```js
const responseData = [
  {
    "code": "AA1", 
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "Ubication 1"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA2", 
    "id": 2, 
    "name": "Ubication 2"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA3", 
    "id": 3, 
    "name": "Ubication 3"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA3A", 
    "id": 3, 
    "name": "Ubication 3A"
  }, 
  {
    "code": "AA4", 
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Ubication 4",
  },
];

const localizarTodasLasInstancias = (propiedad, valor) => {
  return responseData.filter( element => {
      return element[propiedad] === valor;
  })
}

const localizarPrimeraInstancia = (propiedad, valor) => {
  return localizarTodasLasInstancias(propiedad, valor)[0] || {};  
}

console.log('todas');
console.log(localizarTodasLasInstancias( 'code', 'AA4'));
console.log('1ra');
console.log(localizarPrimeraInstancia('id', 3));
console.log('todas');
console.log(localizarTodasLasInstancias('id', 3));
console.log('todas');
console.log(localizarTodasLasInstancias('name', 99));
```